# Type of `@cached_property` is not correctly recognised by pylint

Tags: python, pylint

For me, pylint is giving back an error E1133 (not-an-iterable) for a @cached_property that actually is an iterable. Wondering if this is a bug in pylint or something can be done from my side to prevent this error from popping up.

Functionally the code runs without a problem. Meaning I'm able to iterate over this identified non-iterable.

```py
# doodle.py
from typing import List

from cached_property import cached_property


class Bike:

    @cached_property
    def tires(self) -> List[str]:
        return ["front", "back"]


front_tire = [tire for tire in Bike().tires if tire == "front"]
```

When using @property to make a non-cached property pylint works as expected. Raising no errors on the code block below.

```py
class Bike:

    @property
    def tires(self):
        return ["front", "back"]


front_tire = [tire for tire in Bike().tires if tire == "front"]
```

This is the pylint error that is raised on the @cached_property code block:
doodle.py:11:31: E1133: **Non-iterable value Bike().tires is used in an iterating context (not-an-iterable)**

Just to be I want to mention that I'm not looking to suppress the error with `pylint: disable=not-an-iterable`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `cached-property` library, you can use built-in [`functools.cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property):

```
# Simply replace this
from cached_property import cached_property
# by this
from functools import cached_property
```

The function works exactly the same, but types are correctly recognized by Pylint.

Answer (score -2):

The `not-an-iterable` message may be emitted if `cached_property` is not installed in your environment; I have reproduced this & the message is no longer emitted after installing it with `pip install cached_property`.

Tested using the following Pylint version:

```py
pylint --version
pylint 2.15.5
astroid 2.12.12
Python 3.10.4
```